# Installable Java program talking to the browser

Tags: java

I have a native (installable) Java program that constantly generates certain data (only numbers and text). **I want to send that data to the browser.** I am looking for something similar to node.js with socket.io

**I want to send data (text and numbers only) from java stand alone application running on the client's PC to the client's browser and display this data as a standard website (HTML CSS and JS).**

Take a look at this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ixj7.png). How would you approach this problem?
Take a look at this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed22F.png) as well.

Comment: you should be clear about the flow of datas: where is your program which generate datas: on a user PC, or on a server ? secondly, data doesnt go to the browser. The concept is: the browser fetch the data.

Comment: You're looking for an HTTP server, possible with web sockets.

Comment: Yes, the program runs (and generates) data on the user's PC. I want to send that data to the user's browser.

Comment: @SLaks - http server (tomcat, or anything else) is a tool, not the goal

Comment: you make a confusion: the browser do what it wants (what the user want). Who do what in you application ? who decides to do ? What is the liberty of the user ?

Comment: The uses hits "Open Website" on the installed java program running on the user's PC. Then Browser opens that displays data coming from the java program.

Comment: OK: see my answer. hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So

1 - Everything work on the PC

2 - principal concept: if you choose to use a browser, **the control comes from the user + browser** (which can choose to retrieve data, push buttons, etc.). **Nothing outside can decide to send data to a browser if it didnt ask it.** Function of a browser is *to browse*.

one solution:

- you production app build the data and put it in some file, it can format it in HTML : format option 1 (or raw data : format option 2)
- the data produces can be put on a local file (store option 1), or to be used by a web server (store option 2), even with the same file.
- store option 1: just use your brower to browse your directories:

something like that: file:///C:/truc.html

- store option 2: you need a local web server:

instal some (heavy for each PC): tomcat, or glassfish

- it can deliver static page for format option 1 (same result as store option 1)
- or it can proces with a java/jsp program which retrieve raw data and show it as html (format option 2)

You dont need sockets, or network functions.

In your schema: the background process:

- can work with the webserver (or event read or change some datas in the database).
- dont have to talk with the browser. The browser needs only to talk with the server, which works with your background process.
- your background process can be hosted in the server. It can be scheduled by quartz on glassfish (tomcat, or other web servers). In this design, you finally only need a browser and a client.

Comment: I guess I didn't explain my self correctly. I want to send data (text and numbers only) from java stand alone application running on the client's PC to the client's browser and display this data as a standard website (HTML CSS and JS).

Comment: more explanations in my answer. I think you are misunderstanding about the role of a browser

Comment: Thanks, can you take a look at this screenshot? It will explain more clearly what I want to achieve. [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed22F.png)

Comment: last modification in my answer.

Comment: No, the background process CANNOT talk to the server, or be hosted on the server. I want the values from the background process only to be displayed in the browser, like in here [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed22F.png)

Comment: Assume that the website is already displayed in the browser. I guess JavaScript would be used somehow to access data from the client's side browser from the client's background program.

Comment: then: my store option 1: store locally in a file: your local web browser can simply put url with local file.

Comment: Thanks, that's how I will do it. Is it a good practice to save JSON file (by my java background program) and then read it with JavaScript in the browser? I mean, the JSON file would be updated every second, and the website will be also be updated using AJAX.